# Symfony2 and AJAX error handling on dev environment

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

Using Symfony2 in development mode is very useful: in case of any error in the software, the "ghost" appears and a very useful error screen is shown, with all details in order to resolve it.

But this does not work if a bundle-action is called directly using an Ajax instead of a submit form; using firebug, I saw that, in case of program error, the bug is intercepted and an error page is prepared; nevertheless nothing is shown and simply the Ajax is aborted.

Anyone have encountered the same situation and known how to resolve it?

Comment: Usually in an AJAX request, you have the same information of the Exception but not formatted. If you don't receive this information, probably the error is not manageable by Symfony.
Please check your apache log and paste any useful information :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was simpler than I expected: using jquery "fail" I can simply do as follow, because the symfony2 error page object is returned in jqXHR (assuming that "ajaxexample" was created with "$.ajax(...)" function in jQuery).

```
    ajaxexample.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus)
    {
        var newWindow = window.open();
        if (newWindow != null) newWindow.document.write(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
```

This will open a new document with the symfony2 error page shown.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~